# ApiController consume other API and forward the response

Tags: c#, api, rest, cross-domain, asp.net-apicontroller

i have an API i want to consume, but the API is 3rd party.

www.domain-z.com/API

i would like to make a class that is forwarding the requests on my domain to the domain-z, 
and returning the results to my own domain (to overcome CORS issue)

```
        [HttpPost]
    public WebResponse GetService(JObject jsonResult)
    {
        var myRequest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetServiceRequestModel>(jsonResult.ToString());

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://rest-api.pay.nl/v12/Transaction/getService/json");

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Headers.Add("authorization", "Basic AAAAAAA=");
        request.Headers.Add("cache", "no-cache");
        //request.Headers.Add("content-type", "application/json");
        request.ContentType = "application/json";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { ServiceId = "SLA-673-581" });

            streamWriter.Write(json);
        }

        var response = request.GetResponse();

        return response;
    }
```

It could probably be simpeler than this, but i have no idea.

Comment: What's the issue with your current implementation? And what "CORS issue" are you referring to?

Comment: the cors issue is that i want to have my frontend (javascript) code to consume the 3rd party API, that current implementation i have to create an object reflecting the object from the 3rd party API, and i want to have every other call as well in just a few lines.

Comment: Why not just call the 3rd party API directly from the frontend? Then you also avoid the extra latency caused by going through your own server as middleman AND you avoid inadvertently introducing bugs from your own API.

Comment: Xerillio, if i call the API from the frontend, i have the CORS issue (chrome or whatever browser) is detecting the answer is not from the same domain, and blocking the incoming data. so i need a workaround since the API is not adding cross-site information to the headers.

Comment: It sounds like you may be misinterpreting what the error you see in in the browser is. So I'd suggest you first understand exactly what is blocking you from doing it from the browser. Perhaps the domain disallows CORS requests or perhaps you just need the correct headers. If you do need to do this in the backend you still need to explain what the issue is with the code you've posted.

Comment: I am on domain A.com, and the API is on domain B.com, when i send the request from A.com to B.com its all going fine, B.com is answering and the headers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin should be present in order for A.com to work with the data. if that is not the case then Chrome or whatever modern browser is blocking the request. since i can not change this on B.com domain, its 3rd party, i cannot use it directly from the frontend.

Comment: Ok, that clears things up. But my question still stands: What's the issue with your current implementation?